# Rails controller and javascript: don't give the desired redirect result

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

Users of my website can use a discount coupon. If this coupon entitles them to a 100% rebate, it should update some values for the user and redirect to the root with a flash message. However, the current behavior is that upon submitting the coupon/form, nothing happens on screen; i.e., the page with the form remains displayed, there's not alert message, no redirection, etc. The server log shows that there is action happening but I don't understand why on screen nothing happens. Can anyone please advice?

The form for a user to submit a promotion code:

```
<%= form_for @code, method: :post, url: {action: "checkcode", :controller => 'codes', format: 'js'}, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit Code" %>
  <%= f.text_field :code, :placeholder => "Enter code" %>
  <%= some hidden_fields %>
<% end %>
```

This posts to the following javascript file, which sets some values and updates those values on screen.

```
alert('<%= @message %>');
<% if @sum %>
    $('.js-sum').val('<%= @sum%>');
    $('.js-hash').val('<%= @hash%>');
    $('.js-sum2').html('<%= number_with_precision(@sum, precision: 2) %>');
<% end %>
```

The controller method is as follows:

```
def checkcode
  code = Code.active.by_code(params[:code][:name]).first
  # ... some code that checks 'code' and accordingly sets `@sum`... this works
  if @sum && @sum == 0
    @message = "Accepted"
    @organization = Organization.friendly.find(params[:id])
    if @organization.update_attributes(promo_id: code.name,
                            promo_date: Time.zone.now,
                            exp_date: @organization.check_expiration)
      flash.now[:success] = "A confirmation email is sent to you."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Error"
    end
  end
end
```

The server log:

```
Started POST "/checkcode.js" 
Processing by CodesController#checkcode as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "code"=>{"code"=>"fullrebate"}, "current_sum"=>"100.0", ***, "organization_id"=>"108", "commit"=>"Submit"}
  Code Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "codes".* FROM "codes" WHERE (expiration >= '2015-07-28') AND (code = 'fullrebate')  ORDER BY "codes"."expiration" DESC LIMIT 1
  Organization Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "organizations".* FROM "organizations" WHERE "organizations"."tag" = $1  ORDER BY "organizations"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1  [["tag", "108"]]
  Organization Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "organizations".* FROM "organizations" WHERE "organizations"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "organizations"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 108]]
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."organization_id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."username" ASC  [["organization_id", 108]]
  User Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('test23@example.com') AND "users"."id" != 235) LIMIT 1
   (1.0ms)  SELECT "users"."email" FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."username" ASC
  User Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER('test23') AND "users"."id" != 235) LIMIT 1
  Organization Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "organizations" WHERE (LOWER("organizations"."name") = LOWER('test23') AND "organizations"."id" != 108) LIMIT 1
  Organization Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "organizations" WHERE (LOWER("organizations"."tag") = LOWER('tes23') AND "organizations"."id" != 108) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "organizations" SET "expiration" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "organizations"."id" = $3  [["expiration", "2020-07-31"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-28 16:10:38.906460"], ["id", 108]]
   (3.7ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to https://homepage.com/
Completed 302 Found in 241ms (ActiveRecord: 11.6ms)

Started GET "/" 
Processing by HomePagesController#home as JS
  Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (53.9ms)
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered home_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (399.8ms)
  Rendered shared/_shim.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (3.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3431ms (Views: 3421.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

So on the one hand the server log shows it is executing the controller method and redirecting, but at the same time on screen nothing happens (i.e., does not go to homepage). The line `Processing by HomePagesController#home as JS` strikes me as odd. Is the `as JS` perhaps the cause of the problem and what to do about it?

Comment: `remote: true`  make ajax request and is treated as `js` . remove `remote: true` and `format: js` from the form tag and try if you want `html` request

Comment: Tried it Athar, and then it indeed works. However, I need the javascript/ajax in the (more common) situation that the rebate is less than 100%. Then the javascript is necessary. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: im sorry i didnt get your question.. you need both js and html.?

Comment: Yes I need both. In the post I've left out the part of the controller method that is executed if there is still a price to be paid (so if the rebate is less than 100%). Then ajax is used to update the price that is displayed on screen. (and ajax also displays a message about whether the coupon is accepted). If the coupon entitles the user to a 100% rebate then ajax isn't really needed.

Comment: okay one form can behave with with either ajax request or html request. you cant do both within one. if the controller receive request as `js` it will render `.js.erb` file, and if `html` request it will redirect or render `.html.erb` file. you need to seperate forms to handle both requests according to my knowledge.

Comment: Should it then perhaps work if I place `<% if @sum && @sum == 0 %>` `<% redirect_to root_path %>` `<% end %>` in the javascript file instead of in the controller? I tried it but upon submitting a code, got an error saying: `Missing template codes/checkcode, application/checkcode with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], ...`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84494/discussion-between-athar-and-nick).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for redirection through js request try this.

```
<% if @amount && @amount < 0.01 %> 
  $(window.location.replace("/"))
<% end %> 

alert('<%= @msg %>'); 
<% if @amount %> 
  $('.js-input-amount').val('<%= @amount%>'); 
  $('.js-input-hash').val('<%= @hash%>'); 
  $('.js-text-amount').html('<%= number_with_precision(@amount, precision: 2) %>'); 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very ugly, but it works, change you action code to:

```
def checkcode
  # some code here    
  render js: "window.location = '#{root_path}'"
  # some code here
end
```

This directly render `js` code on the client-side, and change `window` location to expected url(`root_path` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
 redirect_to action: :index
```

or

```
redirect_to '/'
```

instead of

```
redirect_to root_path
```

If it is an issue with async post you could try using something like this

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { :location => path_to_controller_method_url(argument) }
end
```

in your controller.

Comment: Unfortunately this makes no difference: in the server log it says `Redirected to ...` and then whatever specified to redirect to (I also tried other paths). But on screen nothing happens. I think it might have to do with what's in the server as `Processing by HomePagesController#home as JS`. Why `as JS` and what to do about it?

Comment: I edited my answer with a suggestion for async posts.